# Gulp - Fail gulp process if the CSS size is bigger than 50 kb

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

In my project, I have SASS files which are converted by Gulp to CSS files before deployment. What I want to do is to check the size of each compiled CSS file before deployment and fail the process if any of the files is bigger than 50kb.

**What did I do?**

I managed to output the size of each file, but I am not able to fail the Gulp process if the file exceeds 50kb. You can see my Gulp task below:

```
gulp.task('check-CSS-size', () => {
    const s = size({showFiles: true, pretty: true});

    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.css')
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(gulpIf('if s size is bigger than 50kb ', gulpFail(`${s} is bigger than 50kb`)));
});
```

Thank you!

*PS: I am new to Gulp.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this package doesn't allow to do this, it only return total size of files, doing a quick search doesn't seem exists a package that do what you want.

So I think the best is to do it yourself checking the package code or forking it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have all the right pieces in place. Just need to replace your pseudo code statement

```
'if s size is bigger than 50kb'
```

with a real javascript expression

```
(s > 50000)
```

The `gulp-size` package has a `prettySize` parameter with is set to true by default. To get your expression to work you may need to set that parameter to `false` to get a clean number to compare.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I tried this before posting and it does not work, unfortunately.